# Prove that the quotient of a nonzero rational number and an irrational number is irrational

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, rationality-testing

> $0\neq a\in \mathbb Q, b\in \mathbb R \setminus\mathbb Q \text{ (b is irrational)}$ Prove that $\frac a b$ is irrational.

From defintion $a=\frac m n$ such that $m,n\in \mathbb Z, n\neq 0$.

Take the contrapositive: suppose $\frac m {nb}\in \mathbb Q$ prove $\frac m n\notin \mathbb Q$.

Immediate contradiction from defining $m,n\in \mathbb Z, n\neq 0$. Thus $\frac m {nb}$ is irrational.

Well I'm not sure I'm using the contrapositive right and I tried to combine contrapositive with proof by contradiction but I have a feeling I'm wrong...

Comment: From $\frac{m}{nb}$ rational, I would try to show that $b$ is rational, contradicting the fact it isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are definitely mixing up contrapositive and contradiction. It is quite easy to do as a lot of proofs that can be done with one can be done with the other. **Many** students make this mistake early on in their careers. What you should say is that "Suppose $\dfrac{m}{nb}\in\Bbb Q$, then $b\in \Bbb Q$." The reason is that you want to prove "if $b\in \Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q$, then $\dfrac{m}{nb}\in\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q$." The contrapositive of this statement is the statement I gave above because we want to negate each portion (and reverse the direction). The negation of $\dfrac{m}{nb}\in \Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q$ is $\dfrac{m}{nb}\in \Bbb Q$, and likewise for the other. Philosophically, your argument is *okay* but you need to fix it up a little so that you're not mixing up contrapositive and contradiction.

Comment: Yeah I knew I was mixing things up... So to finish it we just add a contradiction since $b$ is irrational then the assumption by contrapositive is false and we're done.

Comment: No. Not quite. Don't think about contradiction here. If we proceed by contrapositive, we have that $\dfrac{m}{nb} \in \Bbb Q$. That is, we can write $\dfrac{m}{nb} = \dfrac{p}{q}$ for some integers $p,q$ (obviously $q\neq 0$). Then by cross multiplying, we have that $b = \dfrac{mq}{np}$, i.e. $b\in \Bbb Q$. Hence **if** $\dfrac{m}{nb}\in \Bbb Q$, then $b\in\Bbb Q$ which is the contrapositive. This in turn says that if $b\not\in\Bbb Q$, then $\dfrac{m}{nb}\not\in\Bbb Q$.

Comment: In a proof by contrapositive, you are "pretending" that you don't know anything. We *know* that $b$ is irrational but with the way the original statement is worded, we kind of have to "forget" that knowledge. Think of it like this: If it is the case that $\frac{m}{nb}$ is rational, what can I say about $b$? Well the obvious thing is that $b$ has to be rational (by our above argument). So... by contrapositive, if $b$ is not rational, then there is no way that $\frac{m}{nb}$ can be rational.

Comment: Oh right right. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem :) Think on it. It takes a while to train yourself to separate contrapositive and contradiction since they are very similar a lot of the time.